# How to Model One to Many relationship pointing to same entity from different entities in EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have an entity as Student

```
public class Student{

..

 public ICollection<Picture> Pictures {get;set;}
```

}

And School entity

```
public class School{

..

public ICollection<Picture> Pictures {get;set;}
}
```

When I create this model and run the migrations I can see that  in Pictures table in the database 2 foreign key properties have been created as StudentId and SchoolId.

It doesn't look right to me to have those foreign keys in the Pictures table.

In the future if another entity needs to have list of Pictures then which means another foreign key property in the Pictures table.

How can I change this behavior in the code first model? Or this is the correct approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a picture cannot be shared among a school and a student, you could create separate entities for the two picture types. The best way to do this is to create a base class and derived classes for each specific picture type:

```
public abstract class Picture 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    // ...
}
public class SchoolPicture : Picture
{
    // ...
}
public class StudentPicture : Picture
{
    // ...
}
```

Then the School entity references the SchoolPicture and the Student entity references the StudentPicture:

```
public class School
{
    // ...
    public virtual ICollection<SchoolPicture> Pictures {get;set;}
}
public class Student
{
    // ...
    public virtual ICollection<StudentPicture> Pictures {get;set;}
}
```

This way, two separate tables are created for the pictures with only a single foreign key to the corresponding parent entity:

[image: Created model]

Comment: Thanks yes I guess this is the best way to implement this. But still not happy to end up with 2 tables in database to hold pictures..

Comment: and in the context class I should add 2 dbset one for SchoolPicture and one for StudentPicture is that right?

Comment: Yes, you'd need to add two DbSets, but you only need to add these if you want to access the pictures directly; in my sample, I've only added the DbSets for School and Student. The advantage of having two separate entities is that you cannot assign a SchoolPicture to a Student by accident.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.yes Now the  StudentPictures and SchoolPictures tables are created in the database. And the annoying bit is they both share the same attributes such as Description, Url, DateAdded etc. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In your Student model, you are saying there is a one-to-many relationship between Student and Picture. Same thing with your School model. So EF adds a foreign key to Picture for both Student and School model. That is the expected behavior.

> It doesn't look right to me to have those foreign keys in the Pictures
>   table.

Based on your Student and School model, I expect EF to add 2 foreign keys to Picture (StudentId and SchoolId). How should it look to you?

> In the future if another entity needs to have list of Pictures then
>   which means another foreign key property in the Pictures table.

If you create another model that contains `ICollection <Picture> Pictures { get; set; }` as a property, then yes, that would create another foreign key in Picture. But if you omit it, it won't.

I'm not sure what you are expecting. Can you elaborate?

Comment: So imagine that I have added 5 different entities the picture collection. which means that any time I add a picture Pictures table 4 of the foreign keys must be set to null as those are not related at all. This does not sound good to me. I go for the polymorphism as @Markus described.

Comment: Ah yes, got it! Yes, @Markus solution would handle that